# What is the difference between 'store' and 'store up' in meaning?

Tags: prepositions

There are two sentences below,

1. He stored the goods in the store.
2. He stored up the goods in the store.

What is the difference between the two sentences?
What is the function of the preposition 'up' here?
Please, tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**up** there conveys the idea of "accumulation".

> The squirrel accumulated acorns for the winter.
>
> The squirrel stored up acorns for the winter.

Without **up** there is no sense of accumulation:

> The leopard stored its kill in a tree.

Comment: Does it(up) add the meaning of accumulation in the sentence? I think that store involves the meaning of accumulation.

Comment: No, you're wrong about that. **store** as a verb without **up** simply means to put something in a place, especially for safekeeping.  *She stored the woolen sweater in a moth-proof bag.*  *She stored her binoculars in the protective case.* There's no sense of *accumulation* there at all.

Comment: I would also add that when using "stored up" to indicate accumulation, you generally don't say "where" you're "storing things up" but instead you address "for what/why" you are storing things up.  Saying, "He stored up goods in the store," makes sense but begs the question, "Why was he storing up?"  It would be more understandable to say, "He stored up fresh water for the expected hurricane."  "Where did he store it?"  "He stored it in the store."